# nano command not found after entering chroot during arch install

Tags: linux, arch-linux, chroot, nano

I am new to Linux and running into a problem while trying to install Arch Linux on bare metal with UEFI.

I have been following the installation guide on the Arch wiki and, like the title says, after I enter the chroot with "arch-chroot /mnt" the nano command is not found. I believe that it should be installed because I used the pacstrap script earlier to install the base, base-devel, linux, and linux-firmware packages to /mnt. Also, I am able to use the nano command before entering chroot.

Is there anything I am missing or misunderstand?

This is also my first post so let me know if there is any other information I should add to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Arch Linux repositories have a much different 'base' group than before, which now only includes the bare minimum required for all installation types (including VMs and minimal "containers"), rather than the previous 'base' group which had a grab-bag of things only useful on physical PCs or not useful at all.

As the installation guide mentions, the new 'base' group **does not** include a text 
editor (nor the kernel, nor manual pages, nor network software, etc.)

You can install nano by running pacstrap again, with the wanted packages listed.

Comment: I thought base-devel included a larger list of packages similar to the old base group. Are there any groups like base that will give me a good starting point or should I just install individual packages?

Comment: I just looked through the base-devel group and it does not include nano. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: just found on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/drlash/install_arch/, run pacman -S nano, after entering chroot during arch install

Comment: or `pacman -Sy nano`